# from date and todate - typescript - expecting little guidance

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

as am new to Typescript/Angular2, few things hard to understand for generating some functionality. so am expecting some guidance from you peoples.

am having editable kendogrid table with datepicker. in that user can enter from date and todate for slot booking. i need to check if same date is enter by one or more user it should highlight already booked date in the table

example : **user A - golfGround_frmDate - 11-july-2017,

                   golfGround_toDate  - 12-july-2017**

if **user B** enter above same date, he ll be notified like that slot is booked in grid table with some color and disable booking button until he give unique date.

if any examples already exists pls share the link

Comment: What is your problem here? Are you asking for a whole solution?

In general it would look like this:

1. catch change/input event (kendo api: Grid)
2. iterate datasource (kendo api: DataSource)
3. change style of rows (kendo api: Grid)

Comment: read my request again. not asking some one write code. just asking if anyone came across the this scenario they can reproduce it. and not able to understand what you said about kendo

Comment: You could support your question with the code you have written so far and we could try to build on this. I am still not entirely sure, what you are asking for. The list I gave you was more less a general list how you would solve the problem and where to look for if you need help.